# PDO/MySQL saving number string with e (exponent) as integer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, integer, exponent

I'm trying to save the following string to the database: `12E2`. Because of the `E` (exponent) MySQL is saving it as "1200" (12 × 10<sup>2</sup>). Is there any way to avoid this? I'm trying to save it to a `VARCHAR` field in the database.

```
$q->bindValue(":field","12E2",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Edit: I've uploaded [a script](http://epicawebshop.com/test.php?value=12E2) which shows the case. The script uses the following code:

```
$fetchQuery=$db->prepare("SELECT `strLocatieNr` FROM `tblShopProducten` WHERE `intID`=254");
$fetchQuery->execute();
$fetchData=$fetchQuery->fetch();
echo "Old: ".$fetchData["strLocatieNr"]."<br />";

$updateValue=@$_GET["value"];
echo "Update value: ";
var_dump($updateValue);
echo "<br />";

$q=$db->prepare("UPDATE `tblShopProducten` SET `strLocatieNr`=:field WHERE `intID`=254");
$q->bindValue(":field",$updateValue,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
echo "Rows affected: ".$q->rowCount()."<br />";

$fetchQuery->execute();
$fetchData=$fetchQuery->fetch();
echo "New: ".$fetchData["strLocatieNr"];
```

Comment: What is the column type in MySQL?

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: @Jules Can you provide more code? I also can't reproduce this with a `VARCHAR` field (with `INT` I get that result, as expected)

Comment: I'v edited the original question with an extended example.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, I cannot reproduce it. Are you sure the field type in the database is varchar(x) where x is the maximum desired length of a string?

Alternatively, are you sure your bind value is surrounded by quotes in the actual code?

If nothing works I'd give a shot to this

```
$q->bindValue(":field",(string)"12E2",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```